# python-cups for CentOS5

Tags: centos, python, cups

I'm try to activate airprint support on CentOS5. I found [this guide](http://www.micromux.com/2010/11/22/airprint-for-mac-on-linux/#more-401), but the `airprint-generate` python script needs cups support. It seems this script needs the `python-cups` lib.

How can I install this lib on CentOS 5 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for CentOS 5.6 with Python 2.4.

Install pycups with:

```
yum install system-config-printer-libs
```

You have to modify airprint-generate.py, line 43 as:

```
from cElementTree import Element, ElementTree, tostring
```